# How can I format an array of objects based on an options array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var objects = [
  {
    'title': 'Title',
    'link': '...',
    'author': 'Author',
    'date': '...',
    'thumbnail_url': '...',
    'comments': 2
  },
  .
  .
  .
];
```

and an array for the options, for example:

```
var options = ['author', 'thumbnail_url']
```

My goal is to write the objects to a list, only showing the properties present in the `options` array. So far my code:

```
objects.forEach(function(obj) {

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = `<a href=${obj.link}>${obj.title}</a>`;

  if (options.includes('author')) {
    li.innerHTML += `<span class="author">${obj.author}</span>`;
  }

  if (options.includes('date')) {
    li.innerHTML += `<time datetime=${obj.date.toISOString()} class="date">${obj.date.toLocaleDateString()}</time>`;
  }

  if (options.includes('thumbnail_url') && obj.thumbnail_url !== "") {
    li.innerHTML += `<img src=${obj.thumbnail_url} class="thumbnail">`;
  }

  if (options.includes('comments')) {
    li.innerHTML += `<span class="comments">${obj.comments}</span>`;
  }

  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
});
```

It's clearly redundant. Is there a smarter way to achieve the same output? (I use vanilla JS.)

Comment: Why not just put all of the information for a book into a single object and all the books into a single array? Then you can extract only what you want from the array/objects based on whatever criteria you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your templates for each property into an object, then iterate options adding appropriate template for each option only:

```
var templates = {
  'author': `<span class="author">${obj.author}</span>`,
  'date': `<time datetime=${obj.date.toISOString()} class="date">${obj.date.toLocaleDateString()}</time>`,
  'thumbnail_url': `<img src=${obj.thumbnail_url} class="thumbnail">`,
  'comments': `<span class="comments">${obj.comments}</span>`
}


objects.forEach(function(obj) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = `<a href=${obj.link}>${obj.title}</a>`;
  // loop over options adding template from template object
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
    if (obj[opt]) {
      li.innerHTML += templates[opt];
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: This would be awesome, but Chrome/Firefox returns with an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined`. Is there a way to store a template literal withput substitution?

Comment: try moving the templates object inside the first `forEach` or put into a function that takes `obj` and `opt` as argumenta and returns the populated template ....  something like `li.innerHTML += getTemplate(obj,opt)`;

Comment: If still have issues...create a js fiddle with some basic data and can tweak it

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:
    var list = document.getElementById('myList');

```
var templates = {
    'author': `<span class="author">${obj.author}</span>`,
    'date': `<time datetime=${obj.date.toISOString()} class="date">${obj.date.toLocaleDateString()}</time>`,
    'thumbnail_url': `<img src=${obj.thumbnail_url} class="thumbnail">`,
    'comments': `<span class="comments">${obj.comments}</span>`
}

objects.forEach( obj => {
    let html = '<a>...</a>';
    for (opt in templates) {
        if (typeof(obj[opt])!=='undefined') {
           html += templates[opt];
        }
    });
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = html;
    list.appendChild(li);
});

// create element and assign html to innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes shure:

```
objects.forEach(function(obj) {
 var li = document.createElement('li');
  ["title","author","thumbnail_url"].forEach(function(key){
    if(obj[key]){
    li.innerHTML += `<a href="${obj[key]}">${obj[key]}</a>`;
    }
  });
 document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options vary a lot, so there's going to be some repetition, no matter what you do. I don't know how much this makes it easier, but I guess You could try creating an array for your options and the various templates you have for them and possible filters. First filter out the options that aren't in your options array. Next, filter out using your template filter, if there is one. Finally, add the element using the template.

```
var possibleOptions = [
  {
    name: 'author',
    template: autor => `<span class="author">${author}</span>`,
  },
  {
    name: 'date',
    template: date => `<time datetime=${date.toISOString()} class="date">${date.toLocaleDateString()}</time>`,
  },
  {
    name: 'thumbnail_url',
    template: thumbnail_url => `<img src=${thumbnail_url} class="thumbnail">`,
    filter: input => input !== "",
  },
  {
    name: 'comments',
    template: comments => `<span class="comments">${comments}</span>`,
  },
];

var options = ['author', 'thumbnail_url'];

objects.forEach(function(obj){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = `<a href=${obj.link}>${obj.title}</a>`;
  possibleOptions
  .filter(option => options.includes(option.name))
  .filter(option => option.filter ? option.filter(obj[name]) : true)
  .forEach(option => {
    li.innerHTML += option.template(obj[name]);
  });
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
});
```